# AngularJS $q service get response in sequence

Tags: angularjs, http, for-loop, q, angular-promise

I have an API that I am posting multiple payloads to and getting the response from the posted payload as expected. Since I'm using the $q.all, I'm getting all the data from the posted payloads as a single promise and then am I only able to display them in the UI. Since the response takes quite some time, instead of displaying it at all, I am trying to get the response data one at a time. I moved the http call inside of the angular.Foreach hoping the call would be made per payload but it still returns all the data to me as a single promise.

Service:

```
function getVarStatData(payload, index, field, stat) {

        var promise = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
            if (field[i]) {

                var varStatData = {
                    user_selection: payload,
                    index_info: index,
                    field: field[i],
                    statistic: stat

                };

               //console.log("stat api payload", varStatData);

                promise.push(postStatData(varStatData));

            }
        }
        return $q.all(promise);

    }

    function postStatData(varStatData){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({
            url: 'API',
            method: "POST",
            data: $.param(varStatData),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function (response) {
            var varStat = response.data;

            deferred.resolve(varStat);


        });

        return deferred.promise;

    }
```

Controller:

```
         arisService.getVarStatData(
                    JSON.stringify(payload),
                    JSON.stringify(config.index_info),
                    statFields,
                    stat
                    )
                    .then(function (data) {

                        $scope.varStat = data;        

                    });
```

Comment: Really not clear what you are trying to do. We don't know how the data in these requests gets used

Comment: The data returns an array of numbers that I loop thru on the front-end...the numbers currently display all at once after the promise is resolved( the $q.all)...BUT since I'm posting mutliple payloads thru the forEach, they are posted to the API one by one and also returned one by one but I don't get them in a way where say, once I get the data from the first posted payload, I'd like to show to and same with the ones after. Makes sense? @charlietfl